# CMake Code removal

Tags: cmake

for delivering software to customers in source code, I'd like to remove code that is encapsulated in `#ifdef` (either the `#ifdef` or the `#else` part). I'd like to do this during calls of CMake's `install()` via target properties. With `get_target_property()`, I can obtain a list of enabled defines, but I can not add `undef`'ed macros to that list via `add_target_definition()` or `set_target_property()` that shall later be removed from the `.c` files. I can imagine that there are solutions available to that situation, but I was unable to find answers here at SO and Google.

- How can I provide a list of enabled and disabled defines to any `install()` mechanism?
- What is the best way to remove disabled code lines from any target `.c` file?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Floxtrott

Comment: Why? What is the problem you want to solve by this? What if the macros defined are not the same for the customers when they try to use the source code?

Comment: As for a possible solution, why not simple present the customers with the preprocessed code? Or come up with a design that doesn't force you to remove or preprocess the files, for example by splitting the code into more files, and not distribute files to customers that should not have those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I question whether filtering out such thins you mention is the right approach. I would use specific Git branches and rebase them on a regular base.

With CMake you will hardly achieve this. It provides no tools to manipulate C source codes. You can generate some headers, but that's basically it.

Use Perl or Python if you insist on filtering.

Comment: I insist on filtering, but can i use cmakes knowledge about active and especially inactive code for filtering the c code with python?

Comment: CMake has no knowledge about (in)active code. It just write a list of pre-processor macros and adds values to is. Parsing this list is an easy task. Difficult is parsing and filtering the C code. Hint: filtering is a major task when done right.